# Export or Import packages from other users

Tags: oracle

I'm having issues export or import a package (including the body) from other user (User that not connect to) through command line. What is the best way to fix this. 
I can view the package via Oracle SQL Developer, within Other user package. But I want to perform this in command line.

So far I'm try to export the package, I have try using following command, unfortunately this not export packages from other users.

```
SET HEAD OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEED OFF
SET TERM OFF
SET LINE 1500
SET NEWPAGE NONE
set pagesize 0
SPOOL C:\app\export\TEST.SQL
PROMPT CREATE OR REPLACE
select trim(text) from user_source
where name='USR_RUNNER' AND type='PACKAGE';
SPOOL OFF
```

Above will only get packages from current user, not from other users.

Comment: Please edit the question and detail the specific error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ALL_OBJECTS` instead of `USER_SOURCE` to view results for all schemas that your user has access to.  You also probably want to use `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` instead of trying to create the DDL yourself with the data dictionary.  Recreating objects can be extremely difficult and `DBMS_METADATA` is the best way to guarantee that you capture the objects correctly.

```
SET HEAD OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEED OFF
SET TERM OFF
SET LINE 1500
SET NEWPAGE NONE
set pagesize 0
SET LONG 999999999
SPOOL C:\temp\TEST.SQL
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PACKAGE', object_name, owner) ddl
from all_objects
where owner = 'SOME_USERNAME'
    and object_type = 'PACKAGE'
order by owner, object_name;
SPOOL OFF
```

Run the below PL/SQL block in the session if you want to export the code without the schema names.  This will allow you to import the script into a different user.

```
begin
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param
    (
        dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'EMIT_SCHEMA', false
    );
end;
/
```

Comment: for me to export, I had to save it under different file then, execute the sql as follows;
@C:\temp\TEST.SQL

Now how do I import a package and replace the existing one under same user?

Comment: @BoomRamada See the edited answer.  There are lots of options in [`DBMS_METADATA`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS026) to transform and remap the different DDL settings.

Answer (score 0):

You are using USER_SOURCE view in your query, use ALL_SOURCE or DBA_SOURCE instead. There is an OWNER column of those views. You can use it in your query's filter.